# SQL server 2008 if else statement in a function and replace int to string based on bool value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `@returnValue` which is a varchar from a function that gets the

**AnimalName** varchar
**AnimalType**  varchar 
**BigSmall** int ( value is either 1 or 0 )

and just make one long string like below

```
@returnValue = @returnValue + AnimalName + ' ' 
+ AnimalType  + '  ' +  convert(varchar, BigSmall) + ': '
```

I want to replace the BigSmall if the value is 0 to 'Small' and if value is 1 to 'Big' and add it to my string @returnValue

Thanks

Comment: If this is homework you should tag it as homework. You should also do a little research, which should have yielded 2 ways to do this using either CASE ... WHEN or IF. Microsoft's SQL reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741(v=sql.105) is always a good place to start.

Comment: This is NOT homework .. I was just stuck with this in a project, yet I am new to programming .. I was going to use if else statement but I was not sure if that might actually work. **Like begin if set end.**

Comment: your link goes to Page not found.

Comment: That's because the closing parenthesis is part of the URL, but stackoverflow isn't recognizing that. Include the parenthesis at the end and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a `CASE` statement around the `BigSmall` field:

```
@returnValue = @returnValue 
                + AnimalName + ' ' 
                + AnimalType  + '  ' 
                + CASE WHEN BigSmall = 0 THEN 'Small' ELSE 'Big' END + ': '
```

Comment: You are awsome, this is resolved, but I have to wait 9 minutes to accept your response. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression:

```
case BigSmall
  when 0 then 'Small'
  when 1 then 'Big'
  else 'Oops' end
```

Comment: Thanks this is resolved I am waiting for a timer so I can mark it as answered. Thanks a lot !